# How to get the absolute current location of the device in android java

Tags: java, android

Perhaps I am misunderstanding, but all the articles i've found for `locationmanager` and `locationlistener` in android refer to the `onLocationChanged()` method.

I want to get the current position of the user, not when it's changed. Am I using the right method? The locationchanged listener is working, and in the emulator runs the method when I change the location.

My app workflow is this:

```
-> App gets request from server for location
-> locationservice starts and stays on for 5 seconds to get the location
-> locationservice saves the location to preferences
-> locationservice stops
-> messaging service sends location to server
```

is a location listener the right method? will it still work if the user does not change location?

here's my location service:

```
public class MyLocationService extends Service {

public LocationManager locationManager;
public LocationListener mLocationListener;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    locationManager =  (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyLocationService.this).edit();
            editor.putString("latitude", Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
            editor.putString("longitude", Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));
            editor.commit();


            System.out.println("Location got changed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    };

    try {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true), 10000, 0, mLocationListener);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
   }
}
```

but the location change is only registering when I do it as the service is open. How can I run that every time the service runs?

Comment: is getLastLocation an option for you? https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: I don't think it would be, I need to get the current position of the user.

Comment: Tried starting service several times: location is returned every time. Seems OK. But I would rather cache location and not connect on every start command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **will** get the user's current position the first time `LocationManager` triggers `LocationListener::onLocationChanged`.

If you are interested only in the current location you can set up the `LocationListener` to receive the first location update and then stop.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // location gotten... store it somewhere
    // and stop the location manager
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this.locationListener);
}
```

Still, `LocationListener::onLocationChanged` will trigger depending on the `criteria` you have set to your `LocationManager`.

For instance:

```
this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this.locationListener);
```

will not be limited by any criteria, it will continuously request location updates.

---

> is a location listener the right method? will it still work if the user does not change location?

Yes

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had a ten second delay in the `minTime` parameter, and now i've taken it out, this is running.